# How to get Error Message When VPN Disconnect

Tags: macos, vpn, disconnect, error-code, system-configuration

I am working on the MAC Application in which I have to create the VPN Connection which I have Done Successfully.

Now I want to know the Reason If My VPN Disconnect.

When the VPN Disconnect I get the callback in my application and there I called the below code : [SCNetworkConnectionCopyExtendedStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConnection/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkConnectionCopyExtendedStatus)

```
dicVPNFailureData =(__bridge NSDictionary *)(SCNetworkConnectionCopyExtendedStatus(connection));
```

Now this return me Dictionary as Below

```
{
    PPP =     {
        DeviceLastCause = 0;
        LastCause = 10;
        Status = 0;
    };
    Status = 0;
}
```

In this Dictionary, I receive the Disconnection cause in **LastCause** Key.

Now I want the message on the basis of that Code.

I also try the below code to get the Message but does not return message related to VPN Disconnection.

```
errorMessage = SCErrorString(strCode.intValue);
```

**Is there any other way I can get the Error Message when my VPN Connection Disconnected.**

Thanks for the help.